# logging level vs handler level

Tags: python, logging, handler

What is the difference between setting the logging level from the logger and from the handler?

The following code:

```
myLogging = logging.getLogger('myOp')
myLogging.setLevel(10)
hdlr = logging.FileHandler(myLogFile)
myLogging.addHandler(hdlr)
myLogging.debug("Message here")
```

will log to `myLogFile`, but this other one won't:

```
myLogging = logging.getLogger('myOp')
hdlr = logging.FileHandler(myLogFile)
hdlr.setLevel(10)
myLogging.addHandler(hdlr)
myLogging.debug("Message here")
```

Why is it that the `FileHandler.setLevel()` won't write to `myLogFile`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`logger` is higher than `handler`. You can image that `handler` is a filter. For example, you have one logger with two handlers:

```
myLogging = logging.getLogger('myOp')
myLogging.setLevel(10)

hdlr1 = xxx
hdlr2 = xxx
hdlr1.setLevel(20)
hdlr2.setLevel(30)

myLogging.addHandler(hdlr1)
myLogging.addHandler(hdlr2)
```

In this case, `logger` itself will log `10+`,`hdlr1` will log more information than `hdlr2`(`20+` vs `30+`).

And back to your case, although you have set `hdlr.setLevel(10)`, but suppose your `logger`'s level is `20`, this is like an inverted triangle.

Answer (score 0):

When LoggingCall(like `logging.info('blah blah'`) is occurred in user code, `Logger` instance determines whether or not to create your `LogRecord` based on its log level. If the record is created, it will go through filters, and then passed to handlers.

So in the second case,

```
myLogging = logging.getLogger('myOp')
hdlr = logging.FileHandler(myLogFile)
hdlr.setLevel(10)
myLogging.addHandler(hdlr)
myLogging.debug("Message here")
```

the log you tried to make(`myLogging.debug("Message here")`) is not created.

[See this logging flow illustration](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) on python documentation.